# Как расширить срез списка? (в одну строку)

Tags: python-3.x, списки

Есть вот такой список:

```
frau = ['Johana','Gretta','Zelda', 'Litgard','Margaret','Helma']
```

Вот мне бы  в его середину вставить еще один список. Встроенный  метод insert() мне не подходит, так как нужно именно расширить список, а не добавить еще один элемент.

Пробую делать вот так:

```
new_list = frau[:3].extend(['Abdul','Madjid','Zahir']).extend(frau[3:])
```

В результате `new_list = None`... Почему это просходит? Я знаю, что `extend()` изменяет исходный список, и ничего не возвращает,но я беру не сам исходный список, а только его срез и все равно получаю `None`...

Провел небольшое исследование и выяснил, что если это делать поэтапно, например вот так:

```
new_list = frau[:3]
new_list.extend(['Abdul','Madjid','Zahir'])
new_list.extend(frau[3:])
print(new_list) #['Johana','Gretta','Zelda','Abdul','Madjid','Zahir','Litgard',
'Margaret','Helma']
```

, то оно работает...

Внутренняя кухня списков - это как устроено?
Поможете разобраться?)

Comment: `>>> Я знаю, что extend() изменяет исходный список, и ничего не возвращает`нифига, `extend` возвращает `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
frau = ['Johana','Gretta','Zelda', 'Litgard','Margaret','Helma']

frau[:3] + ['Abdul','Madjid','Zahir'] + frau[3:]

['Johana', 'Gretta', 'Zelda', 'Abdul', 'Madjid', 'Zahir', 'Litgard', 'Margaret', 'Helma']
```

Comment: Как я сразу и не додумался! Спасибо!